# Is there a stable reduction for a family of vector bundles?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces

**I. General Question**

Consider a one-parameter family of vector bundles $E_t$ on a smooth projective variety $X$ with fixed Chern character $v$. Suppose $E_t$ is Gieseker stable when $t\neq 0$ and $E_0$ is *not* Gieseker semi-stable. **Is there a way to find the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}E_t$ in the Gieseker semi-stable moduli space $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_v(X)$?**

Typically, the limit is a semi-stable coherent sheaf and not necessarily locally free. I'm wondering if there is a way that allows us "modify" the family and produce the semi-stable sheaf at special fiber after a suitable base change?

A counterpart that I have in mind is the Stable Reduction theorem [[Harris-Morrison](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b98867), Prop. 3.17] for curves, which provides us an algorithm to find the limiting stable curve for a flat family of curves with bad singularities at the special fiber. I'm not sure if "stable reduction" is too much to hope for in the realm of the vector bundles.

**II. An Example**

Here is an example I'm working on. On a smooth cubic threefold $X$, there is a rank-two vector bundle $E$ associated to an elliptic quintic curve $C$ on $X$ via Serre construction of the ideal sheaf $I_C$. One can show $c_1(E)=0$ and $c_2(E)=2$. When $C$ is projectively normal, $E$ is Gieseker stable, while when $C$ is not projectively normal (equivalently, $C$ is contained in a hyperplane), $E$ is *not* Gieseker semi-stable (in fact, it is slope semi-stable, though). See [[Markushevich and Tikhomirov](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9809140.pdf), Prop. 2.6]. Therefore, a smooth family $C_t$ of elliptic quintics on $X$ with $C_0$ contained in a hyperplane will produce a family of vector bundles $E_t$ in question.

So how to find the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}E_t$ in $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{2,0,2}(X)$?

[[Markushevich and Tikhomirov](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9809140.pdf), Prop. 2.5] indicates there is a unique pair of lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ on $X$ associated to the non projectively normal curve $C_0$. On the other hand, [[Druel](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0002058), Theorem 3.5] and [[Beauville](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005017), Prop. 6.2(a)] indicate the strict semi-stable sheaves have the form $I_{M_1}\oplus I_{M_2}$ for a pair of lines $M_1,M_2$ on $X$.

These results seem to suggest to us what the limit sheaf is. However, I still cannot find a geometric family of sheaves in $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{2,0,2}(X)$ with $I_{L_1}\oplus I_{L_2}$ appears at time 0.

I appreciate it if anyone could help. Happy new year!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the Harder-Narasimhan filtration of $E_0$. Assume for simplicity it has length 2:
$$
0 \to F_0 \to E_0 \to E_0/F_0 \to 0,
$$
where $F_0$ and $E_0/F_0$ are semistable and the slope of $F_0$ is bigger than the slope of $E_0/F_0$. If $B$ is the parameter space of your family and $i \colon X \to X \times B$ is the embedding of the central fiber, consider the sheaf $E'$ on $X \times B$ defined by the exact sequence
$$
0 \to E' \to E \to i_*(E_0/F_0) \to 0.
$$
Note that the new family $E'$ has $E'_t = E_t$ for $t \ne 0$. On the other hand, if you restrict this sequence to the central fiber and take into account the isomorphism $L_1i^*(i_*G) \cong G$ (because the normal bundle of the central fiber is trivial of rank 1), you get an exact sequence
$$
0 \to E_0/F_0 \to i^*E' \to E_0 \to E_0/F_0 \to 0,
$$
which implies that $E'$ is flat over $B$ and $E'_0$ fits into an exact sequence
$$
0 \to E_0/F_0 \to E'_0 \to F_0 \to 0.
$$
Now the sheaf $E'_0$ is "more semistable" than $E_0$, so iterating this procedure you can eventually modify your family to the one with semistable central fiber.

Comment: Thanks, Sasha. Maybe this is trivial, but I'm confused on why there is a surjective morphism $E\to i_*(E_0/F_0)$ (even for the simplest case $E$ is constant structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X\times B}/\pi^{*}\mathcal{O}_B$ over $B$, if it surjects onto the torsion sheaf $i_*\mathcal{O}_X$, then it seems to send sections to something discontinuous.)

Comment: This is the composition of the canonical morphism $E \to i_*i^*E$ with the pushforward of the morphism $i^*E = E_0 \to E_0/F_0$.

Comment: Got it! So it turns out that we don’t need any base change to modify the family and get the semi-stable sheaf on the special fiber. Is there a reason why there is no local obstruction to get a “local universal family”? For stable reduction of a family of curves (i.e., family of plane curves degenerate to a cuspidal curve), base change is usually needed since the local monodromy is non-trivial.

Comment: I am not sure how to answer this. Maybe the reason is that the authomorphism group of a stable bundle is $\mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$, hence connected, while in the curve case it is not.